# Amazon S3 enable versioning

Tags: php, api, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS for PHP in my application to communicate with amazon S3. I want to enable versioning so I don't overwrite objects with the same keys. I can't find out how to actually enable the feature...

S3 documentation:

> The following request enables versioning on the bucket, bucketName.

```
PUT /?versioning HTTP/1.1
Host: bucketName.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: Wed, 12 Oct 2009 17:50:00 GMT
Authorization: AWS AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE:xQE0diMbLRepdf3YB+FIEXAMPLE=
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 124

<VersioningConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <Status>Enabled</Status>
</VersioningConfiguration>
```

I'm not sure where or how to execute that in php and there's no option in the S3 management console to enable versioning. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `enable_versioning` method of the PHP API like this:

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$s3->enable_versioning($bucket);
```

There's also a `disable_versioning` method to disable versioning.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if this has to be called every time or just once?